# Each data frame row to httr body request with RPS limit

Tags: r

I have a data frame with two variables, for example. I want to POST requests for each row to the server.

I've done this:

```
lapply(seq_along(df$x), function(x){
       POST(some_url, accept_json(),
       add_headers(Authorization = 'Bearer {secret_key})',
       body = as.list(df[x,]), encode = 'json')
})
```

It work's well until the server has RPS limit.

How do I handle this in the best way? Should I extract every 429 http error to another list and repeat POST request, and so on? Or should I slice my list to samples equal to server's RPS?
Help with both variants, please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should respect the server's rate limit. For example, add a `Sys.sleep()` call to your function to delay requests appropriately.